# Sort Gridview with textbox by putting empty values to bottom

Tags: javascript, gridview

```js
// Javascript functions
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#<%=GridView5.ClientID%>").tablesorter({
      textExtraction: function(elem) {
        var $input = $("input[type=text]", elem);

        return $input.val() || $(elem).text();
      }
    }

  );

  if ($('#<%=GridView5.ClientID%>' + ' tr').length > 0) {
    $("#dummyHeader").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#Scrldiv").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#btnExpExcl").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#divbtnupdate").css("visibility", "visible");

  }

  SetDefaultSortOrder();
});

function checkSpcialChar(event) {

  if (((event.keyCode == 60) || (event.keyCode == 62) || (event.keyCode == 38) || (event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 34))) {
    event.returnValue = false;
    return;
  }
  event.returnValue = true;
}



function ExportExcl() {

  var cellNo = $("#<%=NCellLookup.ClientID%>").val();

  if (cellNo != "") {
    document.getElementById('exportIF').src = 'ExportToExcel.aspx?Order=' + cellNo;
    return false;
  }

}


function Sort(cell, sortOrder) {
  var sorting = [
    [cell.cellIndex, sortOrder]
  ];
  $("#<%=GridView5.ClientID%>").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
  if (sortOrder == 0) {
    sortOrder = 1;
    cell.className = "sortDesc";
  } else {
    sortOrder = 0;
    cell.className = "sortAsc";
  }
  cell.setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, " + sortOrder + ")");
  cell.onclick = function() {
    Sort(this, sortOrder);
  };
  document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = 0;
}

function SetDefaultSortOrder() {
  var gvHeader = document.getElementById("dummyHeader");
  var headers = gvHeader.getElementsByTagName("TH");
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, 1)");
    headers[i].onclick = function() {
      Sort(this, 1);
    };
    headers[i].className = "sortDesc";

  }
  var j = 0;
  var wi = 0;
  // var gridD = document.getElementById("<%=GridView5.ClientID%>");

  $('#<%=GridView5.ClientID%> tbody tr:first').each(function() {
    $tr = $(this);
    $('td', $tr).each(function() {

      wi = $(this).width();
      curV = $(this);

      // alert($(this).width())
      for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        if (j == i) {
          //alert(j);
          //alert(i);
          //alert((headers[i].width));
          // alert(wi);
          //alert($("#GridView1 thead tr th:eq(" + j + ")").width());
          // console.log(("#GridView1 thead tr th:eq(" + j + ")").);
          if (i == 0) {
            headers[i].width = 30;
            //griddata[i].width = 50;
            curV.css('width', (30) + "px");
          } else if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 12 || i == 13) {
            headers[i].width = 60;
            //griddata[i].width = 50;
            curV.css('width', (60) + "px");
          } else {
            if (80 > wi) {
              //  alert("1");
              headers[i].width = 80;
              //griddata[i].width = 50;
              curV.css('width', (80) + "px");
            } else {
              headers[i].width = wi;
              //alert(headers[i].width);
              curV.css('width', (wi) + "px");
            }
          }


          //alert($(this).width());
          //break;
        }

      }
      j = j + 1;

    });
  });

}
```

```html
<!-- These are the Scripts used -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- ASP Panel used -->
<asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" Visible="False">
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>enter code here
      <td class="style3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style3">Open NMO Lookup by NCell</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="style1">Enter Cell:</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="NCellLookup" runat="server" Style="font-size: large" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Button ID="NbtnGo" runat="server" Text="View" Width="65px" />&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
              <div id="divbtnupdate" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                    <input type="button" id="btnUpdate" runat="server" onserverclick="btnUpdate_Click" style="width: 65px;" value="Save" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                  </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" id="btnExpExcl" onclick="ExportExcl();" style="visibility: hidden; width: 65px;" value="Export" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <iframe id="exportIF" style="display: none"></iframe> Table used For Headers-
  <table rules="all" border="1" id="dummyHeader" class="grid" style="border-collapse: collapse; visibility: hidden;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">P#</th>
        <th scope="col">MO#</th>
        <th scope="col">FG#</th>
        <th scope="col">Core#</th>
        <th scope="col">Issued</th>
        <th scope="col">Started</th>
        <th scope="col">Requested</th>
        <th scope="col">Family</th>
        <th scope="col">Build Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Barcoded</th>
        <th scope="col">Packed</th>
        <th scope="col">Salvaged</th>
        <th scope="col">Pack</th>
        <th scope="col">NPF</th>
        <th scope="col">Unprocesed</th>
        <th scope="col">Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div id="Scrldiv" style="height: 325px; overflow-y: scroll; visibility: hidden;">
    Gridview for Data -
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="grid">
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P#" SortExpression="Priority">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID='txtPriority' Text='<%# Eval("Priority") %>' runat='server' MaxLength='3' onkeypress='return checkSpcialChar(event)' Width='27px'></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MO#" HeaderText="MO#" SortExpression="MO#">
          <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FG#" HeaderText="FG#" SortExpression="FG#" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Core#" HeaderText="Core#" SortExpression="Core#" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Issued" HeaderText="Issued" SortExpression="Issued" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date MO Started" HeaderText="Started" SortExpression="Date MO Started" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Requested Date" HeaderText="Requested" SortExpression="Requested Date" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Family" HeaderText="Family" SortExpression="Family" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Build Quantity" HeaderText="Build Qty" SortExpression="Build Quantity">
          <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total # Barcoded" HeaderText="Barcoded" SortExpression="Total # Barcoded" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Units Packed" HeaderText="Packed" SortExpression="Units Packed" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Units Salvaged" HeaderText="Salvaged" SortExpression="Units Salvaged" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pack" HeaderText="Pack" SortExpression="Pack">
          <ItemStyle BackColor="#91FF9E" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NPF" HeaderText="NPF" SortExpression="NPF">
          <ItemStyle BackColor="#91FF9E" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Unprocessed" HeaderText="Unprocessed" SortExpression="Unprocessed">
          <ItemStyle BackColor="#91FF9E" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server" MaxLength="500" onkeypress="return checkSpcialChar(event)"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code on the .vb page. This code is called after clicking on View button :

```
Protected Sub NbtnGo_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NbtnGo.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim strConnString As [String] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("WinAuthCgi_master").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim valLook As String = NCellLookup.Text

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(Priority,'') as Priority,isnull(Notes,'') as Notes,Cell, MO#, FG#, Core#,[Issued], [Date MO Started], [Requested Date], Family, [Build Quantity], [Total # Barcoded],[Units Packed], [Units Salvaged],Pack, NPF, Unprocessed FROM Open_MO_Lookup_GPSchedule gp Left Join cgi_master..Molookup_withPriority mt on isnull(gp.MO#,'') = isnull(mt.MO,'') WHERE (Cell = '" & valLook & "') ORDER BY [Requested Date]")
    cmd.Connection = con
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
    sda.Fill(dt)
    GridView5.DataSource = dt
    GridView5.DataBind()
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        GridView5.HeaderRow.Attributes("style") = "display:none"
        GridView5.UseAccessibleHeader = True
        GridView5.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    End If
    Me.lblmsg.Text = ""
End Sub
```

This code is called after clicking on Save Button :

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles btnUpdate.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView5.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim User As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
            User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
            Dim username As String
            username = User.Identity.Name

            Dim Upri As TextBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("txtPriority"), TextBox)
            Dim Unot As TextBox = TryCast(row.Cells(15).FindControl("txtNotes"), TextBox)
            Dim Gmo As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(1).Text)
            Dim valLook As String = NCellLookup.Text
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStr").ToString())
            'Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WinAuthCgi_master").ToString())

            Dim sqltxt As New String("EXEC [DBO].[sp_UpdateMoPriority]  @Upri = '" & Upri.Text & "',@Unot = '" & Unot.Text & "',@Gmo = " & Gmo & ",@Userid = '" & username & "'")
            Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(sqltxt, con)
            con.Open()
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Me.lblmsg.Text = "Updated successfully"

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

After entering a Text in the `TextBox` Besides the "View" Button, the data loads in the `Gridview`, after clicking on the Headers the Data must get sorted, in Ascending and Descending Order, but the Empty values(TextBoxes) must go to bottom in the Orders Ascending/Descending.

I have been looking for it for 2 days but I was unable to find one proper suitable solution.

Comment: Thank you sinsedrix